# How to set json object's value to labels in views rendered dynamically in tableView in swift 3?

Tags: arrays, json, uitableview, dictionary, swift3

I want to set key `name` to labels in view. The problem is the view is based on objects in the json response. For eg. there are two objects in `places`, this will render two view in a single row, which have label for name. So if we see column wise, Pune will be in column 1 and Mumbai in column 2(numberOfSections is 1 only, I am just talking about the UI view). Now id=3 has only 1 object in `places`, that will render only single view with label name "Surat", So how to set data to labels depending upon objects recieved in json. I have used tableView. Have created Two xibs to render single view and double view dynamically in table rows. Please help!!. This issue has taken a lot of time.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "places": [
      {
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "name": "Pune"
      },
      {
        "state": "Maharashtra",
        "name": "Mumbai"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "places": [
      {
        "state": "Punjab",
        "name": "Amritsar"
      },
      {
        "state": "Punjab",
        "name": "Pathankot"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "places": [
      {
        "state": "Gujarat",
        "name": "Surat"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of your JSON is

**Array -> Dictionary -> Array -> Dictionary**

So, let's say you have single view cell and double view cell for this JSON object. First, count how many objects are there in the top level array, which tells you how many cells do you need in your table view. So your code will look like this

```
var topArray: [Dictionary<String, Any>]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let jsonStr = "[{\"id\": 1,\"places\": [{\"state\": \"Maharashtra\",\"name\": \"Pune\"},{\"state\": \"Maharashtra\",\"name\": \"Mumbai\"}]},{\"id\": 2,\"places\": [{\"state\": \"Punjab\",\"name\": \"Amritsar\"},{\"state\": \"Punjab\",\"name\": \"Pathankot\"}]},{\"id\": 3,\"places\": [{\"state\": \"Gujarat\",\"name\": \"Surat\"}]}]"
    let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        topArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Dictionary<String, Any>]

    }catch {
        print("something goes wrong")
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return topArray.count
}
```

Then, in your `cellForRow` method, first count how many items are there in your lower level array to determine which cell you are using. Then deal with them desperately.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let lowerArray = topArray[indexPath.row]["places"] as? [Dictionary<String, String>] {
        if lowerArray.count == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "singleCell") as! SingleCell

            cell.textField.text = lowerArray[0]["name"]

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "doubleCell") as! DoubleCell

            cell.textField1.text = lowerArray[0]["name"]
            cell.textField2.text = lowerArray[1]["name"]

            return cell
        }

    } else {
        return nil //Do your handling
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello Fangming.... Can u please explain in detail with complete json parsing and setting values to UI. Since I am  new to swift I am finding it difficult. I tried but I am getting repetitive values for lowerLevelArray..... Please help.

Comment: I am getting error on this line.... if lowerArray.count = 1 {} (it says Cannot assign property: 'count is get only parameter') and if i do if lowerArray.count==1{} then it is printing Pune Mumbai on all 3 rows.

Comment: Are u getting proper output?? I am using xcode 8.2.1, swift 3

Comment: @279 Sorry updated my answer. So my previous answer is force reading the first element in your JSON. See now I am reading the one from `indexPath`

Comment: Hey Fangming.....!! Thanks a lot.....!!! it worked...... just did small change... instead of topArray[0] do topArray[indexPath.row] and lowerArray.count == 1...... and it's done.... thanks a lot

Comment: @279 This question is already answered. Please create a new question as  the best practice and we will be happy to assist you :)